# google maps v3: how to drop markers, remove, loop again

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been studying Google Maps and I would like to accomplish the following goal:

1) drop markers one by one;

2) delete last marker (so just one is in viewport)

3) drop next marker

4) Have info window opened in each marker

5) repeat operation

I have been trying to twist the code for animations AND trying to set map null (setMap(null)), but with no success after calling the drop function. Any suggestion on how to do that? 
Bottom line: have something like [this](http://www.lkozma.net/wpv/). Of course this has one big extra step of difficult, which is pulling data from database.

Here is the [code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations-iteration?hl=el-GR). 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Marker animations with <code>setTimeout()</code></title>
    <style>
    #map-canvas{
            width:600px;
            height:600px; 
            position: "absolute"; 
            top: 0px; 
            left: 0px; 
            overflow: "hidden";
        } 
        </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
var berlin = new google.maps.LatLng(52.520816, 13.410186);

var neighborhoods = [
  new google.maps.LatLng(52.511467, 13.447179),
  new google.maps.LatLng(52.549061, 13.422975),
  new google.maps.LatLng(52.497622, 13.396110),
  new google.maps.LatLng(52.517683, 13.394393)
];

var markers = [];
var iterator = 0;
var Marker;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: berlin
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
          mapOptions);
drop();
}


function drop(){ 
for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
    var m = neighborhoods[i];

    (function(n){
      setTimeout(function() {
        addMarker(n);
     }, i * 500);
   }(m));
}
}
function addMarker() {
  markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
    position: neighborhoods[iterator],
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
  }));
  iterator++;

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html
```

>

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I loaded you code and the maps loads, but no markers. In order to load the map, I added <body onLoad="createMap()">

Comment: @useruser2060451 - It would be better to add a comment like this on the answer, not the question. I will put my reply there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you want only one marker to display at a time?

Here is some code that does that:

```
$(function() {
    var BERLIN = new google.maps.LatLng(52.520816, 13.410186);

    var NEIGBORHOODS = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.511467, 13.447179),
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.549061, 13.422975),
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.497622, 13.396110),
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.517683, 13.394393)];

    var map = null;
    var marker = null;
    var index = 0;
    var infoWindow = null;

    function createMap() {
        return new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            center: BERLIN,
            zoom: 12
        });
    }

    function dropMarker(map, pos) {
        return new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: pos,
            draggable: false,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });
    }

    function changeMarker() {
        if (marker) {
            infoWindow.close();
            marker.setMap(null);
        }

        var pos = NEIGBORHOODS[index];
        marker = dropMarker(map, pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('lat: ' + pos.lat() + '<br />' + 'lng: ' + pos.lng());
        setTimeout(function () {
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }, 500);

        index = (index + 1) % NEIGBORHOODS.length;

        setTimeout(function () {
            changeMarker();
        }, 2000);
    }

    map = createMap();
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
    changeMarker();
});
```

Notice how the `changeMarker()` function does its work, then uses`setTimeout()` to call itself again. This sets up an infinite loop where `changeMarker()` is called every two seconds.

I used `setTimeout()` to delay the showing of the Info Window by a half second so it does not appear until the drop is finished.

<kbd>[**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/XZpVW/)</kbd>

Comment: I didn't do it in the jsfiddle because it is not necessary there, but if you are using jQuery, you would put the code above inside a call to `$(function() { ... });`. That causes it to execute when the page is ready. I updated the code above accordingly.

Comment: If you are not using jQuery, you could wrap all of the code inside a function named "initializePage", and then add `<body onLoad="initializePage()">`. The important thing is you don't want to call just `createMap()`, you want to execute all three lines of code at the bottom.

Comment: I don't have reputation to give you 100 points, and as a matter of fact, not even one point up. But I did check as the correct answer. This is what I was trying to accomplish. One questions: is the infitne loop here ( index = (index + 1) % NEIGBORHOODS.length;)? I don't understand the '%'. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You made my day. I have been trying to accomplish that for a few days... I got the 15 pt to give the point, but you deserve a lot more than that...

Comment: The infinite loop is a result of `changeMarker()` calling itself (using `setTimeout()` of course). The line of code with `%` is just incrementing `index`, but it causes it to go back to `0` when it is incremented to `4`. The `%` is the modulus (aka remainder) operator. It gives the remainder of dividing the number on its left by the number on its right. The remainder of dividing `3` by `4` is `3`, but the remainder of dividing `4` by `4` is `0`. That is a common technique for causing an incremented value to wrap around with just a single line of code. (No if-statement necessary.)